Boot-Repair for Ubuntu 20.04.x Boot-Repair output and screen captures
I have two VirtualBox VMs, Ubuntu Linux 20.04.x servers that both failed simultaneously and on the same day (11/22/24 @ 1230CST or so).
Here is the screen capture of the results of the boot repair CD. Also the report file generated in case it didn't get to the pastebin.
Neither machine will boot and go to initramfs – image attached -
I'm down on email as the primary and backup are both down, so please reply to my gkasica@icloud.com address. The solution is somewhat urgent because these machines distribute weather forecasting data to about two dozen users and about a dozen fire/police departments in 3 states.
Here is the URL as well as screen captures
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/R74BBTVPfs/
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

User choice:

Is there RAID on this computer? no

==================== blkid (filtered) before lvm activation ====================

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: UUID="274451e8-5707-4f9f-997a-c72706ee527b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda2: UUID="42a4bdb2-071a-4222-a408-56e954ce6ba8" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b1589a36-3b81-4e89-9235-577cf81ae4a7"
/dev/sr0: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2023-12-23-05-05-55-00" LABEL="Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="14eb2669" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/sda3: UUID="QrGTJg-aTC2-mcw8-OWek-zBRX-oTG7-se2ELs" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="2a3deb0b-52d1-43bd-8304-5d88f9c34d3a"
/dev/sda1: PARTUUID="02f70a11-aed4-431e-bb59-c809afc2fbbe"


================================ LVM activation ================================

modprobe dm-mod  
vgscan --mknodes
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
vgchange -ay
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv' [48.00 GiB] inherit
blkid -g

[dmraid -sa -c] no
[dmraid -sa -c] raid
[dmraid -sa -c] disks
[dmraid -sa -c] no
[dmraid -sa -c] raid
[dmraid -sa -c] disks

=================== /boot detected. Please check the options.

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will purge (in order to enable-lvm) and reinstall the grub2 of
mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv into the MBR of sda,
using the following options:  sda2/boot
Grub-efi will not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s


/boot added in mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv/fstab
Mount /dev/sda2 on /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv/boot
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv apt-get -y update
Purge the GRUB of /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
grub-pc available

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
DEBCHECK debOK, grub-pc
DEBCHECK debOK
Please type: sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" dpkg --configure -ansudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get install -fynsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get install -y lvm2nsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub-com*nsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub2-com*nsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y shim-signednsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub-common:*nsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub2-common:*n
Then type: sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv" apt-get install -y grub-pc

Unhide GRUB boot menu in mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv/etc/default/grub

========== Reinstall the grub-pc of /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ==========

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.17

==> Reinstall the GRUB of /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv into the MBR of /dev/sda

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[39859]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 26173: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[39859]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 26173: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[39859]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 26187: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[39859]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 26187: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[39859]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 26200: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[39859]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 26200: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[39859]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 26215: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[39859]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 26215: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[39859]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 26283: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[39859]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 26283: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-200-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-200-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-196-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-196-generic
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[39859]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 26685: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[39859]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 26685: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[39859]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 26781: /bin/sh

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 2048 
    of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,gpt2)/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg /grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: SVGA II Adapter from VMware
Live-session OS is Linuxmint 64-bit (Linux Mint 21.2, victoria, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: VirtualBox from innotek GmbH
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   no-grubenv, update-grub,    not-far
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ng, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  fstab-has-bad-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : is---sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Disk identifier: 4CB54191-F185-4675-A00A-23CB96E1F959
       Start       End   Sectors Size Type
sda1     2048      4095      2048   1M BIOS boot
sda2     4096   2101247   2097152   1G Linux filesystem
sda3  2101248 104855551 102754304  49G Linux filesystem
Disk mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 48 GiB, 51539607552 bytes, 100663296 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:53.7GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA VBOX HARDDISK:;
1:1049kB:2097kB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
2:2097kB:1076MB:1074MB:ext4::;
3:1076MB:53.7GB:52.6GB:::;
mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv:51.5GB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:51.5GB:51.5GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME                      FSTYPE      UUID                                   PARTUUID                             LABEL                  PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                                      
├─sda1                                                                       02f70a11-aed4-431e-bb59-c809afc2fbbe                        
├─sda2                    ext4        42a4bdb2-071a-4222-a408-56e954ce6ba8   b1589a36-3b81-4e89-9235-577cf81ae4a7                        
└─sda3                    LVM2_member QrGTJg-aTC2-mcw8-OWek-zBRX-oTG7-se2ELs 2a3deb0b-52d1-43bd-8304-5d88f9c34d3a                        
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4        274451e8-5707-4f9f-997a-c72706ee527b                                                               

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                   Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  28.7G  34% /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
/dev/sda2                         686.9M  23% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda2                         ext4            rw,relatime

============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================

/dev/mapper:
control
ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

======================== sda2/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =========================

Ubuntu   274451e8-5707-4f9f-997a-c72706ee527b
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   0.229049683 = 0.245940224    grub/grub.cfg                                  2
   0.141407013 = 0.151834624    grub/i386-pc/core.img                          1
   0.616275787 = 0.661721088    vmlinuz                                        1
   0.491275787 = 0.527503360    vmlinuz-5.4.0-196-generic                      1
   0.616275787 = 0.661721088    vmlinuz-5.4.0-200-generic                      1
   0.491275787 = 0.527503360    vmlinuz.old                                    1
   0.705074310 = 0.757067776    initrd.img                                     3
   0.257694244 = 0.276697088    initrd.img-5.4.0-196-generic                   4
   0.705074310 = 0.757067776    initrd.img-5.4.0-200-generic                   3
   0.257694244 = 0.276697088    initrd.img.old                                 4
sprunge.us ko ()

Files:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/n9dsecvygssses31ioe64/ADMELvt4bT-BY4E9O-4mWgU?rlkey=dvk60fvuklgfxlfo9ftmu7ax2&st=5yv1p2jb&dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/qkb80cus6wavw3yc1zgcx/boot-repair.log.txt?rlkey=ix98dsagp7a6txlzqdp9ujav7&st=l6zz2nkh&dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/yk1i9dn7z835lb66i9f1n/Boot-Info_20241123_0455.txt?rlkey=mrny05ex3zbdyi189jnd94xp2&st=37zhdkwd&dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/j3lt28k1ryrvey4ifx96t/2024-11-22_22-25-15.pdf?rlkey=quewejw7fs5fefnf0i957urts&st=gx6bdbv8&dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/z9tujwzwp0cryuorxf9he/2024-11-22_21-49-37.pdf?rlkey=466xeq4k3q9qtp0trn0jlfmqe&st=20wb0mz4&dl=0



We found a backup Primary mail server we can easily clone and rename for the backup. Case Closed.
